# How to join two RDDs : value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, importerror

I'm using Spark 2.1.0 and Scala 2.10.6

When I try to do this :

```
val x = (avroRow1).join(flattened)
```

I get the error :

```
value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

Why do I get this message? I have the following import statements :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
```

This is my code :

```
 val avroRow = spark.read.avro(inputString).rdd
  val avroParsed = avroRow
    .map(x => new TRParser(x))
    .map((obj: TRParser) => {
      val tId = obj.source.trim
      var retVal: String = ""
      obj.ids
        .foreach((obj: TRUEntry) => {
          retVal += tId + "," + obj.uId.trim + ":"
        })
        retVal.dropRight(1)
    })

 val flattened = avroParsed
 .flatMap(x => x.split(":"))
 .map(y => ((y),1)).reduceByKey(_+_)  .map { case (a, b) => {
val Array(first, second) = a.split(",")
((first, second), b)
 }}.saveAsTextFile(outputString)


 val avroRow1 = spark.read.avro(inputString1).rdd
  val avroParsed1 = avroRow1
    .map(x => new TLParser(x))
    .map((obj: TLParser) => ((obj.source, obj.uid, obj.chmon))) .map { case (a, b, c) => ((a, b), c) }
    .saveAsTextFile(outputString1)


    val x = (avroParsed1).join(flattened)
```

**UPDATE**

This is my sample output for avroRow1 :

```
((p872301075,fb_100004351878884),37500)
((p162506011,fb_100006956538970),-200000)
```

This is my sample output for flattened :

```
((p872301075,fb_100004351878884),2)
(p162506011,fb_100006956538970),1)
```

This is the output I'm trying to get :

```
((p872301075,fb_100004351878884),37500,2)
(p162506011,fb_100006956538970),-200000,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

*`join()`* operation is only available on PairedRDD.In your case it is not paired RDD. The reason being , you need a common key to join two RDDs but with generic RDD it is not possible. Try convert your  `avroRow1 & flattened` into (key,value) and then perform join.

> A Resilient Distributed Dataset (RDD), the basic abstraction in Spark.
>   Represents an immutable, partitioned collection of elements that can
>   be operated on in parallel. This class contains the basic operations
>   available on all RDDs, such as map, filter, and persist. In addition,
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions contains operations available
>   only on RDDs of key-value pairs, such as groupByKey and join;

Answer (score 0):

```
val avroRow1 = spark.read.avro(inputString1).rdd
```

Here you are converting a DF to rdd. You should convert avroRow1 to  (key,value) pair. Then apply join operation.

Answer (score 0):

.saveAsTextFile(outputString) can cause problems because this changes the return type of the variables. Rather than saving as individual files before joining, the RDDs can *persist()* and the final output can be saved by .saveAsTextFile in this manner :-

```
 val flattened = avroParsed
 .flatMap(x => x.split(":"))
 .map(y => ((y),1)).reduceByKey(_+_)  .map { case (a, b) => {
val Array(first, second) = a.split(",")
((first, second), b)
}}   


 val avroRow1 = spark.read.avro(inputString1).rdd
  val avroParsed1 = avroRow1
    .map(x => new TLParser(x))
    .map((obj: TLParser) => ((obj.source, obj.uid, obj.chmon))) .map { case (a, b, c) => ((a, b), c) }


val res = avroParsed1.join(flattened).saveAsTextFile(outputString1);
```